# How to select rows where column contained a string

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to find rows where a column contains a particular string.

I have a table that contains a column which contains values separated by commas (,).

How can I find the rows that contain a certain value?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE 'value,%'
OR yourcolumn LIKE '%,value,%'
OR yourcolumn LIKE '%,value'
```